# Minimum generalized variance for outlier detection

Tags: variance, outliers

I'm currently reading the paper [Distribution of Variables by Method of Outlier Detection](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3389806/) and am trying to understand the section on `Minimum generalized variance`

If my understanding is roughly correct, it basically starts off with no points and then adds points to a data-set. Each point is then assign a variance score. The further away the data point is from the median the more variance it accrues. The paper does a much better job at explaining it and is very accessible. My question is concerned with the section on cutoffs. For multi-variate outliers it uses the formula

$M_{G}+\sqrt{\chi_{0.975 . p}^{2}}\left(q_{3}-q_{1}\right)$

I understand the role of `q1` and `q2` but could anyone explain to me what the $\chi_{0.975 . p}^{2}$ in the section of the formula represents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment:  Short answer: *I don't really know.* Explorations follow.

In the linked paper, it seems early on that $p$ is degrees
of freedom (or observations or dimensions). Then just after display (6) the author
seems about to define $\chi_{0.975,p}^2$ when the sentence
ends abruptly. At (7) this expression occurs again.

My ***guess*** is that this is the value that cuts probability 0.025 from
the upper tail of $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = p).$ Taking $p=2$ in (7)
this would lead to $\sqrt{\chi_{0.975,p}^2} = 2.716,$ which might make
sense in context. Computation in R:

```
sqrt(qchisq(.975, 2))
[1] 2.716203
```

However, a more common use of subscript notation with $\chi^2$
is that the probability in the subscript is cut from the *lower* tail of the distribution (a 'percentage point'). Then the quantity would be $0.225.$

```
sqrt(qchisq(.025, 2))
[1] 0.2250236
```

*Note:* The author quotes several well-known statisticians as being opposed
to the removal of outliers, unless traced to a specific mistake. Then
seems to ignore this advice with various suggestions for detecting and
removing inconvenient outliers from multivariate data.

Comment: Hi @BruceET, Thank you very much for taking the time out to explore the question. I went to the end of the research paper and found the `mgv.output < -outmgv(full.data,y = NA,outfun = outbox)` which appears to come from this [book](https://books.google.de/books?id=_tAJr4ooOM8C&pg=PA231&lpg=PA231&dq=%22outmgv%22&source=bl&ots=miCEOjY7Ig&sig=ACfU3U2-k2s3i_7SubDXIKXTI_IaNlFPyA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiv5NPx6vzjAhUDDewKHeaIAj0Q6AEwA3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22outmgv%22&f=false). It seems to be the square root of the .975 quantile where p is the degrees of freedom (pg 230)

Comment: The formula in the question is a familiar one in nonparametric statistics: one computes or estimates a "pseudo-standard deviation" by means of a robust statistic such as the IQR (as in this case) and then rescales it by a universal constant so that the pseudo-SD for a *Normal* distribution equals the usual SD.  I believe that's all that's going on here.